# Can 総指揮 be used outside of a military context?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4JDxrrSGT0

「えーー、こんにちは、あるいはこんばんは。えー、糸井重里です。

今度、任天堂から、えー、マザーというタイトルで、えー、僕の、えー、組織、監督脚本というなんか大げさ が/な 触れ込みで、マザーという新しいロールプレイングゲームが出ます。

I'm not sure if its そうしき 総指揮 general director, executive producer

Comment: Supposed your transcription 組織 seems 総指揮 and 大げさが/な is 大げさな.

Comment: I've rather rarely seen 総指揮 in a military context, by the way...

Answer (score 3):

It is used for Executive Producer according to Wikipedia.

- [エグゼクティブ・プロデューサー](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B0%E3%82%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96%E3%83%BB%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC)

> エグゼクティブ・プロデューサー （英：executive producer）は、プロデューサーのさらに上の職で、管理職・幹部に当たる。**製作/制作、製作総指揮/制作総指揮などの名義でクレジットされる場合が多い**。

Note that Nintendo seems to use katakana vesion of エグゼクティブ・プロデューサー for CEO of the company.

> コンピュータゲーム業界で見られる。任天堂においては「エグゼクティブ・プロデューサー」の肩書は代表取締役社長に対してのみ使用されている。

Comment: You all have been really great! I wasn't even expecting any replies.

Answer (score -2):

In tech and entertainment, people make up ridiculous titles as we all know, and in that sense it's not impossible. But, It's not likely to happen - for one thing, it could read そうしき　葬式　"funeral" and the moment something goes wrong and the project dies, it'd be all over 2chan. On this particular matter, wikipedia lists him as Director ディレクター, so given the international nature of game development these days, that's what I'd use.

Comment: 総指揮 is something we see very often in credits. It's not ridiculous at all.